# Пишу код как в обучающем видео, не получается (UE 4.2x, C++)

Tags: c++, unreal-engine-4

Пишу код аналогичный видео[image: пример кода] (Пытаюсь использовать GetOwner()->GetName()). Ругается, что "Использование указателя на тип неполного класса не допускается." Я абсолютно с этим согласен, просто не ожидал, что UE4 у себя так поменяют все. Вижу, что надо подключить вот это - https://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/GetOwner/index.html. Подключаю, после этого начинает ругаться BeginPlay(). Пишет класс UObject не содержит члена BeginPlay. Прошу подсказать хотя бы куда копать, в чем ошибка. В идеале прошу показать правильный код использования GetOwner().

Comment: Ссылку на видео в студию. И где тут `BeginPlay()`?

Comment: Видео предоставить не могу, т.к. видеоуроки платные, а их публикация = нарушение авторских прав. Когда добавляю в инклуд то, что описал выше, то подсвечивается 19 строчка

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за внимание. Нашел ответ нужно было инклудить в .cpp, а не в .h

Comment: И как мы должны были догадаться? Из скриншота этого вообще не видно, а больше вы ничего не выложили.

Comment: Извините, впредь буду выкладывать все, что относится к вопросу.